# Recently installed ubuntu 18.04 erasing windows, and show no wifi adapter found

Tags: networking, realtek, grep, lspci

on typing : lspci -vnn | grep Network
it showed : 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]

I am using HP Notebook - 15q-by004ax
Wifi was working on windows.